# Extending the visible area of a UITableView past the contentSize

Tags: uitableview, ios4, uiscrollview

I would like to replicate the behaviour of the 'Edit profile' view of the Instagram app, illustrated by the following images:

[Image 1](http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/9498/photo1ko.png) |
[Image 2](http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/576/photo2ng.png)

i.e. When the UITableView is resized (so that the user can still scroll the form when the keyboard is shown):

1. The scroll bar goes down to the top of the keyboard toolbar (see 'Image 2' above).
2. The table is still viewable below that point, through the transparent toolbar (see 'Image 1' above).

If I set the frame to go down as far as the top of the toolbar, (1) is satisfied but (2) isn't.
If I set the frame to go down as far as the top of the keyboard, (2) is satisfied but (1) isn't.
I have also tried setting the frame to go down as far as the top of the keyboard and then setting the contentSize attribute to be the size of the screen down to the top of the toolbar, which also doesn't seem to work either.

Any thoughts?